# minDate in wdcalendar not working

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery wdcalendar plugin and want to add minDate attribute in its datepicker function. I have tried almost everything adding minDate but nothing works out.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
$("#stpartdate").datepicker({ minDate: 0, picker: "<button class='calpick'></button>"});
```

Comment: if possible provide fiddle.